# Установить дату методом, принимающем день, месяц и год

Tags: java, дата, calendar

Перерыл кучи документации и понял, что для работы с датой лучше всего использовать Calendar. Но возник такой вопрос: возможно ли в JAVA задать нужную дату напрямую без лишних преобразований, что-то по типу `myDate.set("28.12.2016");` ну или через запятую?

Подскажите, в какую сторону копать либо киньте примеры (именно на установку даты и ее извлечение).

P.S. Пишу консольное приложение, ввод даты осуществляется пользователем вручную.

Comment: А LocalDateTime лучше как по мне =) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html

Comment: Вообщето Date как раз имеет такй конструктор Date(int year, int month, int day)

Comment: в java-8 добавили новое api для работы с датами (пакет java.time). Если вы не можете использовать java-8 (напр. андроид), посмотрите библиотеку Joda Time

Comment: @zRrr теперь, начиная с  версии Android N поддерживается Java 8)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как я понимаю, нужный тебе метод [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int))

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2016, 6, 10);
```

Для отображения даты используйте [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Например:

```
        SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMMM", Locale.getDefault());
        String myString = dayFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Задавайте нужный паттерн для вывода даты, в примере выше результат будет "Вс, 12 июня"

А при вводе от пользователя ничто Вам не мешает минусить на единицу введеный месяц.

Комментарий от @zRrr:

> SimpleDateFormat умеет разбирать строки с датами, примерно так:
>
> ```
> Date date = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd.MM.yyyy" ).parse( "28.12.2016" );
> ```
>
> и так лучше разбирать пользовательский ввод, если формат даты в строке
>   известен.

Comment: Аккуратнее. Месяцы в `Calendar` считаются с 0 (январь), так же `set` не сбросит время в 0 (это все указано в документации по ссылке). Еще числа, начинающиеся с `0` трактуются, как восьмеричные (большой беды в случае с датами не будет, просто код с `09` не скомпилируется).

Comment: Да, конечно, согласен с Вами, исправил в ответе. Про время в вопросе не было ничего, естественно его необходимо так же скидывать, либо использовать метод set (int, int, int, int, int, int)

Comment: Да, я читал о том, что нумерация месяцев идет с нуля, следовательно декабрь это 11 месяц. Именно по этому мне и показался Calendar не удобным в плане использования. Если пользователь укажет дату рождения 01.08.1989, то это будет двойной ошибкой.

Comment: @Bogdan Дополнил ответ интересующими Вас ответами.

Comment: @zRrr спасибо поправил недочеты, просто переписал не думая дату из трэя

Comment: еще можно добавить, что `SimpleDateFormat` умеет разбирать строки с датами, примерно так: `Date date = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd.MM.yyyy" ).parse( "28.12.2016" );` и так лучше разбирать пользовательский ввод, если формат даты в строке известен.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month, day);                     //вводим дату
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
String formatted = format1.format(c.getTime());
```